# How can I shorten the full path to the file, to the name of the file in djano admin forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a standard Django admin form.
When the file is uploaded in the file selection box, I would like to leave only the file name, instead of the full path in the static.
Is this possible without editing the template, but only by overriding a formset, form, or model methods?
[image: inline with files]

In the picture above the button, change the display of the line "ws_document_studygroup/2021/2/123123123123123123png" to "123123123123123123png". But without changing the real path in the model.
Please advise the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found different resolve this issue.

I override ClearableFileInput widget and clearable_file_input.html template

```
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput
import os


class CustomClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    template_name = 'custom_clearable_file_input.html'

    def format_value(self, value):
         """
         Return the file object if it has a defined url attribute.
         """
         if self.is_initial(value):
              setattr(value, 'file_short_name', os.path.basename(str(value)))
              return value
```

and in template file change string to:

```
<a href="{{ widget.value.url }}">{{ widget.value.file_short_name }}</a>
```

And just add widget to file field:

```
class StudyGroupDocumentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
file = forms.FileField(widget=CustomClearableFileInput)

class Meta:
    model = StudyGroupDocuments
    fields = '__all__'
```

And add the form to Inline.

Hope it is helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding an [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) getter to your model class:

```py
import os


class Document:

    def __init__(self, full_path: str):
        self.full_path = full_path

    @property
    def filename(self) -> str:
        return os.path.basename(self.full_path)
```

The [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) function takes a path and returns the path segment following the final slash character (in other words, the filename).

```py
>>> doc = Document("ws_document_studygroup/2021/2/123123123123123123.png")
>>> doc.filename
123123123123123123.png
```

So all you need to do is use this property in your template.

Comment: Thx, I use property code in a custom widgets.